# Create class with same fields as another class with few exceptions

Tags: java, annotations, dto

Suppose I have class A like this

```java
class A {
    private String Id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
   //... some other hundres of feilds
}
```

How can I create another DTO named CreateA which contains all fields for A except the one I mention like id ?

something like this

```java
@sameAs("A")
@skip("Id")
class CreateA {}
```

is there any java library for this ?

Comment: No, you pretty much have to copy the fields over manually.

Comment: @LouisWasserman but what if people adds more hundred useless fields over time? I will have to edit Create Dto each time. There is possibility of mismatched names

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  (I suggest you don't design classes with hundreds of fields that require all of them to be present.)